# Find Name of Array obj from Json

Tags: javascript, json

[image: Please find attachment where Exact data I have. I want to read key name of Array. Like "CIRTGroupBox1", "CIRTGroupBox2", "CIRTGroupBox3"]

Here I want to read key name of obj.
Like  "CIRTGroupBox1", "CIRTGroupBox2"

Comment: Does `groupBoxesTemp.CIRTGroupBox1` do it?

Comment: [MDN: Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an object literal.  [There's no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var arr = [{
 'CIRTGroupBox1': ''
}, {
 'CIRTGroupBox2': ''
}, {
 'CIRTGroupBox3': ''
}];

// Using array.map() method
var usingMapKeys = arr.map((obj) => Object.keys(obj)[0]);

// Using Object.entries() method
var usingEnteriesKeys = arr.map((obj) => Object.entries(obj)[0][0]);

console.log(usingMapKeys);

console.log(usingEnteriesKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Object.keys method in JS like below

```
var keys = Object.keys(groupBoxesTemp);
```

This will return string array and each item in it is the key of this object.

If you want to read values pertaining those 2 keys, you can do like below using the for-in loop:

```
 for(item in groupBoxesTemp){
     console.log('key is: ', item);
     console.log('value is: ', groupBoxesTemp[item]);         
}
```

Based on your screenshot, temp is an array of objects which has 3 objects in it. You can do that too like below:

```
temp.forEach(function(item, index){
    //key for all objects in the array will be logged.
    console.log( Object.keys(item) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is it?

```js
var x = {
 "ob1": "value",
 "ob2": {
  "ob21": "value"
 }
};

var keys = Object.keys(x);

console.log(keys);
```